# Requirements to build J2ME mobile application?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, multimedia, j2mepolish

I want to build some application on J2ME devices but I have no documentation of the device. How to get more familiar with the device details so that I can develop some applications.

I want to build applications which will use the Camera, Speaker, and Mic of the device. On Android, it is easy to build this application but for the J2ME devices, I am not much familiar with the default classes and libraries which would be useful to built such application.

Also, I want to send mms to another device or to upload it on internert using application. So what classes/libraries/plugins are required to deploy in for building such application.

Comment: Have you read the [official documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156363.html)?

Comment: Thank you, Danilo, I went through this documentation and found it very useful to create the MultiMedia apps. I have few mobile devices but I found that only one device supports such MMAPI, other has MMAPI properties I checked using (System.getProperty("supports.video.capture")). When I created Camera app it is not able to access this resources. For Camera I used (player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");) but fail to get camera access. For different mobile does they have different locators. If so how can I get the detail about the Locator to access this resources?